# ¿Como ordenar y guardar objetos de dos arraylist en un nuevo arraylist en Java Android?

Tags: java

Buenas con todos tengo una duda muy grande, me han dado dos archivos .json

**vehiculo.json**

```
[
    {
        "IdVehiculo": "0000000001",
        "Placa": "B77950",
        "CodVeh": "0002415",
        "RegistradoVehiculo": "S",
        "RegistradoPiloto": "S",
        "RegistradoCopiloto": "S",
        
    },
    {
        "IdManifiesto": "0000000002",
        "Placa": "T00900",
        "CodVeh": "0002382",
        "RegistradoVehiculo": "S",
        "RegistradoPiloto": "S",
        "RegistradoCopiloto": "S",
        
    }
]
```

**pasajero.json**

```
 [
    {
        "IdVehiculo": "0000000001",
        "IdPasajero": "00000077",
        "Asiento": "01",
        "NombrePasajero": "ARENAS BOB ESPONJA",
        "Embarcado": "N",
        "FechaEmbarque": "26/06/2020 3:03:57"
    },
    {
        "IdVehiculo": "0000000002",
        "IdPasajero": "00800122",
        "Asiento": "01",,
        "NombrePasajero": "PEREZ GUITIERREZ ANDRES",
        "Embarcado": "N",
        "FechaEmbarque": "26/06/2020 2:01:52"
    },
    {
        "IdVehiculo": "0000000001",
        "IdPasajero": "00800123",
        "Asiento": "02",,
        "NombrePasajero": "SANCHEZ CORONADO RAUL",
        "Embarcado": "N",
        "FechaEmbarque": "26/06/2020 2:01:52"
    },
]
```

Luego los convertí en Arraylist y los guarde en sus debidas clases con objetos

**VehiculoResponseDto**

```
public class VehiculoResponseDto implements Parcelable {

 public String IdVehiculo;
 public String Placa;
 public String CodVeh;
 public String RegistradoVehiculo;
 public String RegistradoPiloto;
 public String RegistradoCopiloto;
```

**PasajeroResponseDto**

```
public class PasajeroResponseDto implements Parcelable {

 public String IdVehiculo;
 public String IdPasajero;
 public String Asiento;
 public String NombrePasajero;
 public String Embarcado;
 public String FechaEmbarque;
```

Con dichos datos cargados en cada uno de mis objeto hago lo que tengo que hacer y funciona bien, el problema es que ahora yo debo unir esas dos clases con sus objetos y convertirlos en json, me podrian dar una mano de como convertir esas dos clases en una sola o alguna idea de como obtener el siguiente formato de json

```
    [
   {
        "IdVehiculo": "0000000001", 
        "Placa": "B77950",
        "CodVeh": "0002415",
        "RegistradoVehiculo": "S",
        "RegistradoPiloto": "S",
        "RegistradoCopiloto": "S", 

        "Pasajeros":[
          {
            "IdVehiculo": "0000000001",
            "IdPasajero": "00000077",
            "Asiento": "01",
            "NombrePasajero": "ARENAS BOB ESPONJA",
            "Embarcado": "N",
            "FechaEmbarque": "26/06/2020 3:03:57"
           },
           {
            "IdVehiculo": "0000000001",
            "IdPasajero": "00800123",
            "Asiento": "02",
            "NombrePasajero": "SANCHEZ CORONADO RAUL",
            "Embarcado": "N",
            "FechaEmbarque": "26/06/2020 2:01:52"
           }
             ]

   },

   {
         "IdVehiculo": "0000000002",
         "Placa": "T00900",
         "CodVeh": "0002382",
         "RegistradoVehiculo": "S",
         "RegistradoPiloto": "S",
         "RegistradoCopiloto": "S",

        "Pasajeros":[
          {
            "IdVehiculo": "0000000002",
            "IdPasajero": "00800122",
            "Asiento": "01",
            "NombrePasajero": "PEREZ GUITIERREZ ANDRES",
            "Embarcado": "N",
            "FechaEmbarque": "26/06/2020 2:01:52"
          },
          ]
    }

]
```

Para convertirlo en json no es tanto el problema seguro que hay tutoriales por ahí, lo que me gustaría saber por favor es como unir esas dos clases para poder transformarlas en el formato que deseo, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Puedes usar el método [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) para ordenar el ArrayList y para unir los dos ArrayList podría hacer uso de [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-).

Comment: Agrega lo que has tratado por favor. saludos